# App crashes when clicking button,Android Studio(Java)

Tags: java, android

```
Hello fellow programmers!
I have a very disturbing situation here...I'm developing an Android App with several activities.In them I have buttons.The app itself is for measuring calories and other sports releated stuff.
I have a calorie calculator which I have built in the app,spread across 2 activities.In activity 1,the calculator measures the Basal Metabolic Rate and In the second activity,the app calculates the calories needed,when clicking a button for the desired activity level.My app crashes in the second activity,when clicking "Sedentary" button and I have no clue why,because these buttons are built just like the buttons in my first activity.I'll post photos and my code so you can get orientation.
Btw,the app crashes also when clicking "Null Data" in the first activity with the BMR...The button doesn't have any coding on it and does nothing.I'm not calling calculate() method in the second activity,instead I tried doing the button click in the main method,but it still didn't work.
```

Hello fellow programmers!
    I have a very disturbing situation here...I'm developing an Android App with several activities.In them I have buttons.The app itself is for measuring calories and other sports releated stuff.
    I have a calorie calculator which I have built in the app,spread across 2 activities.In activity 1,the calculator measures the Basal Metabolic Rate and In the second activity,the app calculates the calories needed,when clicking a button for the desired activity level.My app crashes in the second activity,when clicking "Sedentary" button and I have no clue why,because these buttons are built just like the buttons in my first activity.I'll post photos and my code so you can get orientation.
    Btw,the app crashes also when clicking "Null Data" in the first activity with the BMR...The button doesn't have any coding on it and does nothing.I'm not calling calculate() method in the second activity,instead I tried doing the button click in the main method,but it still didn't work.[First Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBj2k.png)[Second Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iluzX.png)

```
`package com.petartonkov.foodandsportsinfo;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CalorieCalculator extends AppCompatActivity {

    public Button nextstepbtn;
    public TextView BMR;
    public EditText height;
    public EditText weight;
    public EditText age;

    public void calculate() {
       final Button calculateBMR = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CalcBtn);
       final TextView BMR = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_BMR);
       final EditText weight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_weight);
       final EditText height = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_height);
       final EditText age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_age);
        assert calculateBMR != null;
        calculateBMR.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                assert weight != null;
                float weight1 = Float.parseFloat(weight.getText().toString());
                assert height != null;
                float height1 = Float.parseFloat(height.getText().toString());
                assert age != null;
                float age1 = Float.parseFloat(age.getText().toString());
                float BMR1 = (13.75f * weight1 + 5.003f * height1 - 6.755f * age1) + 66.75f;
                assert BMR != null;
                BMR.setText(Float.toString(BMR1));
            }
        });
    }
    public void calculate1() {
        final Button calculateBMR = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CalcBtnFemale);
        final TextView BMR = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_BMR);
        final EditText weight = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_weight);
        final EditText height = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_height);
        final EditText age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_age);
        assert calculateBMR != null;
        calculateBMR.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                assert weight != null;
                float weight1 = Float.parseFloat(weight.getText().toString());
                assert height != null;
                float height1 = Float.parseFloat(height.getText().toString());
                assert age != null;
                float age1 = Float.parseFloat(age.getText().toString());
                float BMR1 = (9.563f * weight1 + 1.85f * height1 - 4.676f * age1) + 655.1f;
                assert BMR != null;
                BMR.setText(Float.toString(BMR1));
            }
        });
    }
    public void init4(){
        nextstepbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.NextStepBtn);
        nextstepbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), CalorieCalculatorSecondActivity.class);
                intent1.putExtra("BMR", (Parcelable) BMR);
                startActivity(intent1);
            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calorie_calculator);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            init4();
calculate();
        calculate1();
    }

}
`

      `  package com.petartonkov.foodandsportsinfo;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class CalorieCalculatorSecondActivity extends CalorieCalculator {

    public void totalcalories() {
        final Button calculateBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_sedentary);
        final TextView totalcalories = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_totalcalories);
        final TextView BMR = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_BMR);
        assert calculateBtn != null;
        calculateBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                assert BMR != null;
                float BMR2 = Float.parseFloat(BMR.getText().toString());
                float totalcalories1 = BMR2 * 1.2f;
                assert totalcalories != null;
                totalcalories.setText(Float.toString(totalcalories1));
            }
        });
    }
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_calorie_calculator_second);
            Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    final Button calcBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_sedentary);
            final TextView totalcalories2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_totalcalories);
            final TextView BMR1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView_BMR);
            assert calcBtn != null;
            calcBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    assert BMR1 != null;
                    float BMR3 = Float.parseFloat(BMR1.getText().toString());
                    float totalcalories4 = BMR3 * 1.2f;
                    assert totalcalories2 != null;
                    totalcalories2.setText(Float.toString(totalcalories4));
                }
            });
        }
    }
`
```

`

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Enter your data below to calculate your BMR(Basal Metabolic Rate) and then enter your level of physical activity to determine your daily calorie needs.BMR-this number is the calories needed from the body to maintain basic living functions."
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="go to next step"
        android:id="@+id/NextStepBtn"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="BMR:"
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:textColor="#070707"
        android:layout_below="@+id/CalcBtn"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="CAL"
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView_BMR"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textColor="#980606" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="NULL DATA"
        android:id="@+id/btn_nulldata"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/NextStepBtn"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/NextStepBtn"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView2"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClicked"/>


    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText_age"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp"
        android:hint="Enter age"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText_weight"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText_age"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:hint="Enter weight(In KG)"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/NextStepBtn"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/NextStepBtn" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText_height"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText_weight"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:hint="Enter height(In CM)" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/textView_BMR"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/NextStepBtn"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/NextStepBtn"
        android:textColor="#980606" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CALCULATE BMR-MALE"
        android:id="@+id/CalcBtn"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText_height"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView13" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="CALCULATE BMR-FEMALE"
        android:id="@+id/CalcBtnFemale"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/CalcBtn"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView13" />


</RelativeLayout>`
```

`

```
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="SELECT YOUR LEVEL OF PHYSICAL ACTIVITY:"
        android:id="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="sedentary"
        android:id="@+id/button_sedentary"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView10"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:onClick="setContentView" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="moderately active"
        android:id="@+id/button_moderatelyactive"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button_sedentary"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView14" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Very active"
        android:id="@+id/button_veryactive"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button_sedentary"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Extremely active"
        android:id="@+id/button_extremelyactive"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_veryactive"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button_moderatelyactive"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button_moderatelyactive" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Sedentary - Little or no exercise,little walking"
        android:id="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button_veryactive"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textColor="#e10e0e" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Lighty active - light exercise 1-3 times/week + walking"
        android:id="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView14"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textColor="#e10e0e" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Moderately active - exercise 3-5 times/week + walking"
        android:id="@+id/textView16"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView15"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textColor="#e10e0e" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Very active - hard exercise 5-7 times/week + walking"
        android:id="@+id/textView17"
        android:textColor="#e10e0e"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView16"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="TOTAL CALORIES NEEDED:"
        android:id="@+id/textView18"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textColor="#080808" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/textView_totalcalories"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView18"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView18"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView18"
        android:editable="false"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="0" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="CAL"
        android:id="@+id/textView20"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView_totalcalories"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textColor="#090909" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="NULL DATA"
        android:id="@+id/btn_nulldata2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/button_sedentary"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/button_sedentary" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Extra active - hard exercise 5-7 times/week + physical job + walking"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:textColor="#e10e0e"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView17"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Lightly active"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button_extremelyactive"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_extremelyactive"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/button_extremelyactive" />

</RelativeLayout>`
```

`

```
                                                                                 --------- beginning of crash
06-14 06:10:35.167 2481-2481/com.petartonkov.foodandsportsinfo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                 Process: com.petartonkov.foodandsportsinfo, PID: 2481
                                                                                 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.TextView.getText()' on a null object reference
                                                                                     at com.petartonkov.foodandsportsinfo.CalorieCalculatorSecondActivity$2.onClick(CalorieCalculatorSecondActivity.java:44)
                                                                                     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
                                                                                     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

`

Comment: Post your logcat, and for the future question read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and  [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'll keep it in mind.The logcat was posted at the time of the crash.

Comment: Which class is using 1st layout and 2nd layout? which one is activity_calorie_calculator_second

Comment: Class CalorieCalculator is 1st layout

Comment: Class CalorieCalculatorSecondActivity is 2nd layout

Answer (score 0):

This metod is throwing

```
     calcBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                assert BMR1 != null;
                float BMR3 = Float.parseFloat(BMR1.getText().toString());
                float totalcalories4 = BMR3 * 1.2f;
                assert totalcalories2 != null;
                totalcalories2.setText(Float.toString(totalcalories4));
            }
        });
```

You have no TextView (BMR1) with the id of textView_BMR in your secondActivity layout

Comment: The error is,that when I call my object in the second activity,it is null.It tells me it's null.But in the first activity it is not null,instead it is the textview that shows you your BMR.How to get it in the second activity,so it is not null?

Comment: Are you tying to access the view in first activity  from second activity?

Comment: Yes.But Android Studio allows me to do it,e.g. access all the textviews in the first activity in the second one.

Comment: That's not good idea, its throwing null because view from first activity is not there anymore when you start the second activity. You can make it to work but as i said that's really really bad way of doing this.

Comment: Any idea how to get the value from the first activity and get it in the second one?

Answer (score 0):

To pass the value from one activity to another you can use Intent extra

Intent extra is a bundle of additional information you want to pass from one activity to another. You can create extras like this

```
//First Activity
Intent i = new Intent(FirstActiviy.this, SecondActivity.class);   
String value = "some string you want to put in the extra";
int value2 = 14

//put extra as key-value pairs
i.putExtra("KEY", value);
i.putExtra("KEY2", value2);

startActivity(i);


//Second activity 

//Get the values from previous Activity by keys you set 
String stringValueFromPreviousActivity = getIntent().getStringExtra("key");

//Note: when you getting integer as the second parameter pass the default value if there is no passed integer
int intValueFromPreviousActiviy = getIntent().getIntExtra("key",4);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried setting up the calculator in one activity...I rearanged the buttons and guess what..?My float from BMR TextView is NULL,althrough I have a string in BMR TextView.Why is this happening?I wrote the code for the total calories in another method,in the first activity.

```
public void calculatetotalcalories()
    {
        final Button calcbtn_sedentary = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_sedentary);
        final TextView totalcalories = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_totalcalories);
        calcbtn_sedentary.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                float BMRconverted= Float.parseFloat(String.valueOf(BMR));
                float totalcalories1 =BMRconverted*1.2f;
                totalcalories.setText(Float.toString(totalcalories1));
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.It was an null object reference in the start of the activity.Everything now works!